# Deploying a Sails.js app to dokku-alt? Buildpack error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, docker, sails.js

When deploying Sails.js to dokku-alt on DigitalOcean, I get the following error. It seems to be failing when installing Sails.js, but I couldn't find any information on this error message. I would appreciate insight on what this error message means and how to resolve this issue. Thanks for the help!

Terminal

```
-----> Building dependencies
       No cache available
       Installing node modules
       npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
       npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6

       > sails@0.11.0 preinstall /tmp/build/node_modules/sails
       > node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js


remote: /tmp/buildpacks/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/lib/build.sh: line 166:   104 Killed                  npm install --quiet --userconfig $build_dir/.npmrc 2>&1
remote:        105 Done                    | indent

-----> Build failed

       WARNING: Node version not specified in package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
       You can also try reverting to our legacy Node.js buildpack:
       heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v63

       Love,
       Heroku
To dokku@45.55.65.138:chessrabbit-server
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@12.34.56.789:chessrabbit-server'
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^0.8.1",
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-browserify": "^3.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-react": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
    "grunt-shell": "^1.1.2",
    "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.3",
    "kaiseki": "^0.5.6",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "~0.11.0",
    "sails-auth": "^1.2.7",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0",
    "sails-hook-babel": "^5.0.1",
    "sails-mongo": "^0.11.2",
    "stripe": "^3.6.0",
    "tracer": "^0.7.4",
    "uuid": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "sails lift --prod --port 80"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/henry/test.git"
  },
  "author": "henry",
  "license": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually running out of memory on my VPS. The solution was to simply add a swap partition.

A detailed guide on how to add a swap partition can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04